# Duplicate class in firebase-common and jetified-firebase-components with library version from BoM

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using a selection of Firebase libraries together, so I'm using the BoM in order to ensure that the libraries will work together, here is my gradle.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-installations'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting errors such as this:

> Duplicate class
> com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer found in
> modules firebase-common-18.0.0-runtime.jar
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0) and
> jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)

I can see the following "dependency" help from gradle:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 18.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0 -> 18.0.0
```

And these dependencies only exist in the `implementation`s above ^

`com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0` is only here:

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config -> 19.2.0
|    ...
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-installations:16.3.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0
```

I get the feeling the problem may be being caused by jetifier but can't be sure.

I've tried removing both libraries completely but obviously they are used and therefore cause a crash at runtime.

I understood using the bom would protect me from library conflicts like this..? So I'm wondering if I'm missing something none-version related.

Comment: You should post an issue on GitHub with your full, minimal configuration that reproduces the issue. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Any update on this? I am getting the same issue with OneSignal Plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I switched jobs so never solved this. I ended up manually adding all versioned components until it worked (suboptimal for sure!)

Answer (score 0):

1. add these lines to android > app > build.gradle

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
2. cd android > `.gradlew clean`
3. cd ..  > `npm start -reset-cache`

check now